# Error: docker daemon is not running. [/bin/lib/functions.plugin.sh:93]

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine

I have downloaded Docker Toolkit and open through shortcut, after that IP address was generated successfully.

I cloned the Athena code through Git from https://github.com/athena-oss/athena into test folder and Athena folder is created after cloning the code.

I entered the below commands:

```
cd athena
./athena
```

It's displaying that Git and Docker are installed but it's throwing some error like:

```
Error: docker daemon is not running. [/bin/lib/functions.plugin.sh:93]
```

Comment: Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: i checked with the below commad "docker-machine status" and it's running. i hope this is the only thing to run Docker. Please let if any other process to run Docker daemon @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Answer (score 0):

Try this, inside the same terminal window:

- Restart your docker machine: `docker-machine restart`
- Re-set environment variables `eval $(docker-machine env)`
- `cd athena` and run once more `./athena`

Comment: @scott-weldon ?